# How to show that Z-score is a standard normal random variable?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I'm struggling with this question:

**If $X$ is $N(\mu; \sigma^2)$, then show that $Z = \frac{(X - \mu)}{\sigma}$ is a standard normal random variable; that is, $N(0;1)$**

---

Here is how far I have gotten:

$$P(Z \leq z)=P(X \leq z\sigma +\mu) = \int_{\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}^{z} \! \frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

I used $x = y\sigma + \mu$ as my change of variable.

1.) Is my result correct so far?

2.) And what is my next step? This integral is out of my scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rightmost expression should be$$\int_{-\infty}^{z\sigma+\mu}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\mathrm dx.$$No substitution is required to obtain this, just the definition of $N(\mu,\,\sigma^2)$. The exercise is to rewrite this as$$\int_{-\infty}^z\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{z^2}{2}\mathrm dz$$with the substitution $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$.